# Rails GROUP BY, COUNT

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, count, group-by

I have a Tag table, that looks like this:

```
NAME  | USER_ID |  OBJECT_ID 
---------------------------
"fun" | 1       | 1
"fun" | 2       | 1
```

Object is a taggable object, nothing more than that. Now, the problem I'm experiencing is:
I want to display non-duplicate tags for the object, but with ability to say which user each tag belongs to.

So, I have declared following association for the taggable object:

> has_many :tags, :group => "name", :order => "count(`tags`.`name`)
>   DESC, `tags`.`name` ASC"

So, it does two things: 1) groups by tag name -> eliminates the duplicates 2) orders the tags by the number of records

But, at the same time I need to determine if the visitor on the page (logged-in user) has left any tags or not, and it is not possible, because GROUP selects random tag from the list and only one user can be determined.

How would you solve this issue ?

Comment: So, do you want to fetch the tags posted by this user alone?

Comment: During the listing all of the tags (unique tag names) I want to somehow mark the tags, that were left by the user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to post the whole answer again. But, this link talks exactly what you are looking for. http://www.justskins.com/forums/aggregate-functions-does-value-149176.html#post501498

The logic is to use JOIN on the same table.

Comment: Thanks. Looks interesting, but how would I adapt it to rails ?

Comment: This is probably not what I need. I'm not producing the tags for any particular user. I just need to know if user has listed any of tags or not (but to display them all)